# Leaflet: flyToBounds location of bounding box returned by PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, leaflet, polygon, extents

I want to simply center my map on the search result of a polygon using leaflet. I thought to return the bounding box, as this is closer to what I actually need.

I want to use flyTo()

I see a possible way to do this by using Leaflet?

I have a thought to do this

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON (geom) AS geom, Box2D(geom) as bounds, ST_YMax(Box2D(geom)) as ymax, ST_YMin(Box2D(geom)) as ymin, ST_XMax(Box2D(geom)) as xmax, ST_XMin(Box2D(geom)) as xmin FROM nation_shapes WHERE (condition)
```

and then pass it to

```
mymap.flyToBounds([[ymax, xmax],[ymin, xmin]])
```

Though this seems inefficient. I would like to be able to get this information from the object I am already passing back if possible, or convert something like `Box2D(geom) as bounds` which would be more efficient than calling it 4 times, I think.

Comment: Is this Leaflet or PostgreSQL question? Leaflet `flyTo` method takes as argument single lat,lng point, `flyToBounds` method takes bounding box as argument.

Comment: @TomazicM thanks, fixed. It's both because I am storing the data in PostgreSQL / PostGIS and displaying with leaflet. I am searching for a way to display a BOX type in leaflet, if possible. I have it working now with the way I mention first.

Comment: This is then PostgreSQL / PostGIS question which is beyond my knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with...

```
SELECT Box2D(geom) as bounds, 
    ST_YMax(bounds) as ymax,
    ST_YMin(bounds) as ymin,
    ST_XMax(bounds) as xmax,
    ST_XMin(bounds) as xmin
    FROM nation_shapes WHERE (condition)
```

...as PostgreSQL's SQL engine and query planner is smart enough to figure things out and not duplicate work.

If you want to not return the bbox from the query, then

```
SELECT ymax, ymin, xmax, xmin FROM (
  SELECT Box2D(geom) as bounds, 
    ST_YMax(bounds) as ymax,
    ST_YMin(bounds) as ymin,
    ST_XMax(bounds) as xmax,
    ST_XMin(bounds) as xmin
    FROM nation_shapes WHERE (condition)
  )
```

> which would be more efficient than calling it 4 times, I think.

Beware of [premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize). Do not assume efficiency in SQL queries unless you take some time to [`EXPLAIN` the query](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Using_EXPLAIN).